# Parametrization of a line segment

Tags: calculus

I'm a bit confused as I originally thought I had the correct answer. However, I checked again and read that my parametrization of $x$ and $y$ in terms of theta CANNOT pass through the points $(0,2)$ and $(4,0)$. How can I parametrize this then? Regardless of how I do it, it always seems like my parametrization will pass through $(0,2)$ and $(4,0)$
[image]

Comment: There isn't anything wrong with your answer, the question basically asks for the line segment with those points as the endpoints (but not really including them, that is you couldn't substitute 0 or $\frac{\pi}{2}$ in for $\theta$)

Comment: It marks my answer as incorrect... Maybe it's because my expression does include the two endpoints? But I can't think of any other way to parametrize this so that the endpoints are not included.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean

Comment: Maybe it wants you to use sine and cosine ? Or, $\tan \theta = y/x$ ? Also, maybe crop that picture to remove your name :)